# Excel 2016 Password Protection with unique password and able to filter rows

Tags: excel

I have a file that needs to be Protected by password. However, the code I have for protecting and unprotecting is a generic one and not a specific one. Hence, anyone can put there own password into the message box to unlock or lock. I would like only one password to be used for protecting and unprotecting the workbook. Here is the code that I am utilizing and I appreciate your advisement:

```
Sub sbProtectAllSheets()
Dim pwd1 As String, pwd2 As String

Call mcr_HideRowsColumns

pwd1 = InputBox("Please Enter the password", "Password Input")
If pwd1 = "" Then Exit Sub
pwd2 = InputBox("Please re-enter the password", "Password Input")
If pwd2 = "" Then Exit Sub
'Check if both the passwords are identical
If InStr(1, pwd2, pwd1, 0) = 0 Or _
InStr(1, pwd1, pwd2, 0) = 0 Then
MsgBox "You entered different passwords. No action taken"
Exit Sub
End If
For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Protect Password:=pwd1, AllowFiltering:=True
Next
MsgBox "All sheets Protected."


'-------------------------------------------
Sheets("Home").Select
Range("A1").Select

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

And Unprotect:

```
Sub sbUnProtectAll()
On Error GoTo ErrorOccured
Dim pwd1 As String

pwd1 = InputBox("Please Enter the password", "Password Input")
If pwd1 = "" Then Exit Sub
For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Unprotect Password:=pwd1
Next
Call mcr_UnhideRowsColumns

MsgBox "All sheets UnProtected."

Exit Sub
ErrorOccured:
MsgBox "Sheets could not be UnProtected - Password Incorrect"

Exit Sub
End Sub
```

The Call features are just hiding and unhiding rows that I do not want users to see.
Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Why not change `If pwd2 = "" Then Exit Sub` to `If pwd2 <>pwd1 Then Exit Sub` ? It would seem to save a lot of code.

Comment: Just FYI - Passwords in Excel are relatively easily broken (if a user wants to).  Just see some [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=break+excel+password).  Not saying you shouldn't use them, just want you to be aware.  Why do you want a password? From your comment/answer below, you just don't want people deleting some cells? Not necessarily trying to protect the entire workbook/worksheet?

Comment: @BruceWayne - You are absolutely correct, most people can break the password. I locked down the VBA as well. Most of these people entering data in are hourly workers that do not have massive Excel skills. If they want to get in, more power to them. We only want them changing certain cells for project time, those are unlocked for editing. Other sheets need to remain unlocked.

Comment: @Jeeped, thanks for your suggestion, however, the password anybody puts in the message box like "Password" only needs to match the second input "Password." Hence, they can put any password they want. I need it to be a password that I dictate. I will admit I could be totally missing something. Most likely!

Comment: Ah, yes that makes sense.  So you're saying you want *only* the password (for example), "TRexPassword" to work, and anything else not to?

Comment: @BruceWayne You are correct my friend. All the code that I have seen in my searching has not produced a defined password like "TRexPassword" Thanks again for your interest and time helping.

Comment: Maybe I'm overlooking something, but why not just add `if pwd1 <> "TRexPassword" Then ...` to make sure it's the one you want.  Or, make a global variable `mainPW = "TRexPassword"`, then it'd be `if pwd1 <> mainPW Then ...` and in your Unlock one, just do `ws.Unprotect Password:=mainPW`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138675/discussion-between-t-rex-and-brucewayne).

Answer (score 0):

I found this: Sincere apologies to the original person who wrote it and Thanks!

```
Sub protectAll()
Dim myCount
Dim i
myCount = Application.Sheets.Count
Sheets(1).Select
For i = 1 To myCount
    ActiveSheet.Protect "your-password", true, true
    If i = myCount Then
        End
    End If
    ActiveSheet.Next.Select
Next i
```

End Sub

```
Sub UnprotectAll()
    Dim myCount
    Dim i
    myCount = Application.Sheets.Count
    Sheets(1).Select
    For i = 1 To myCount
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "your-password"
        If i = myCount Then
            End
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Next.Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Which sets a password on all sheets, but if the user needs to enter data somewhere then you need to un-protect those cells...
I use it to stop people "accidently" deleting my formulae - usually with the excuse "I couldn't understand what it was doing so I deleted it".
Hope it helps.